# Javascript not changing div's margin on Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

This site I'm working on (terraterraband.com) basically adds a menu button when the screen size gets to 600px(I think). I want the logo image's margin to change to 0 at the same moment. For now, I'm trying to change it using javascript, though I know there's probably a way to do it with css. For some reason it doesn't change. When wordpress adds the image, there is no Id, just a class, which is why I had to use the getElementsByClassName function. The wordpress theme has a window to add javascript, which puts it in the head. What have I done wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   var logo=document.getElementsByClassName("site-logo");
   if(window.width<=600){
    logo[0].style.margin="0px";
   }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a media query?

Answer (score 0):

For Responsive coding try to use **innerWidth**.

```
jQuery(function(){
   var logo=jQuery(".site-logo");
   if(window.innerWidth<=600){
    logo[0].style.margin="0px";
   }
});
```

Comment: @JohnCulbreth  in http://www.terraterraband.com/ I saw it is working. 
After reducing the browser width refresh your page once, you will see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

It was a little difficult to infer what you were after. But I believe you are wanting to have less white-space between your logo & the menu. 
 [image: reduce white space below logo]

If that's the case, then you are trying to change the wrong element. One of the parent container's of your logo has a fixed height of `200px`. So what you'd actually want to change is `.site-branding .container`.

The easiest solution here is to use a [CSS Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .site-branding .container {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Your menu also doesn't change at `600px`, but rather at `1000px`. So I'd recommend changing the media query to reflect that.